# xslt parse XML string into variable and use Xpath

Tags: xslt, dom, internet-explorer-9, xslt-1.0, jscript

My (simplified) input XML file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <MESSAGE>&#60;pd&#62;&#10;    &#60;cdhead version&#61;&#34;13&#34;/&#62;&#10;&#60;/pd&#62;</MESSAGE>
    </DATA_RECORD>
</main>
```

The MESSAGE element value is a character-escaped XML instance. It represents the following XML:

```
<pd>
    <cdhead version="13"/>
</pd>
```

I would like to apply an xsl transformation on the input XML and somehow parse the MESSAGE contents into a variable and use Xpath expressions to access its details.
I tried adding a javascript function as below, but the object returned by the script apparently is of an incorrect DOM subclass (see result underneath). For completeness, I added an extra function that returns the DOM contents as a string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:my="http://example.com/my"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ms my">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <ms:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="my">
        <![CDATA[
        function parseToDOM (input) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
        doc.loadXML (input);
        return doc.documentElement;
        };
        function parseToXMLString (input) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
        doc.loadXML (input);
        return doc.documentElement.xml;
        };
        ]]>
    </ms:script>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATA_RECORD">
            <xsl:variable name="DOM"><xsl:copy-of select="my:parseToDOM (MESSAGE)"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="XML"><xsl:copy-of select="my:parseToXMLString (MESSAGE)"/></xsl:variable>

            <msg1><xsl:value-of select="$XML"/></msg1>
            <msg2><xsl:value-of select="$XML" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></msg2>
            <dom><xsl:copy-of select="$DOM"/></dom>
            <version><xsl:value-of select="$DOM/pd/cdhead/@version"/></version>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <msg1>&lt;pd&gt;
    &lt;cdhead version="13"/&gt;
&lt;/pd&gt;</msg1>
    <msg2><pd>
    <cdhead version="13"/>
</pd></msg2>
    <dom/>
    <version></version>
</root>
```

How can I make the Jscript function return a result that allows the use of Xpath?
By the way, is there some XSLT 1.0 function available that allows parsing the escaped XML string to a result that allows the use of Xpath?

**ADDITION**

I have been trying some variations and got closer to a solution. First, Altova XMLSpy allows choosing the xsl processor, and the above resulted when using the built-in one. Of course I need MSXML 6.0 and when choosing that one, errors occurred as I had to parse input.text instead. But I only succeeded in being able to use Xpath expressions in the result after doing extra stuff in the javascript. It transpired that while `&#60;` and the like are parsed into `&lt;` etcetera, this is not enough to arrive at the proper DOM result. So I resorted to unescaping the input string first.
But I hit another snag: where the below works fine, it does not when I use `input.text` instead of the literal below.

See below the xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:my="http://example.com/my"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ms my">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <ms:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="my">
        <![CDATA[
        function parseToDOM (input) {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
            doc.loadXML (unescapeXML ('&#60;pd&#62;&#10;    &#60;cdhead version&#61;&#34;13&#34;/&#62;&#10;&#60;/pd&#62;'));
            //doc.loadXML (unescapeXML (input.text));
            return doc;
        };
        function unescapeXML (str) {
            var ostr = str;
            ostr = ostr.replace (/&#34;/g, '"');
            ostr = ostr.replace (/&#60;/g, '<');
            ostr = ostr.replace (/&#61;/g, '=');
            ostr = ostr.replace (/&#62;/g, '>');
            return ostr;
        };
        ]]>
    </ms:script>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATA_RECORD">
        <xsl:variable name="msg" select="my:parseToDOM (MESSAGE)"/>
        <tst><xsl:value-of select="$msg/pd/cdhead/@version"/></tst>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now results in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<tst>13</tst>
</root>
```

Which is exactly what I want.

But as remarked above, when I comment the parsing of the literal and use the input instead, like so:

```
//doc.loadXML (unescapeXML ('&#60;pd&#62;&#10;    &#60;cdhead version&#61;&#34;13&#34;/&#62;&#10;&#60;/pd&#62;'));
doc.loadXML (unescapeXML (input.text));
```

I get the following error (in Altova XML Spy with MSXML 6.0 as xslt parser):

```
XSL transformation failed due to following error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error
'undefined' is null or not an object
line = 10, col = 3 (line is offset from the start of the script block).
Error returned from property or method call.
```

Which points at the first javascript replace statement.

And also, IE9 cannot process the following properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xslt"?>
<main>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <MESSAGE>&#60;pd&#62;&#10;    &#60;cdhead version&#61;&#34;13&#34;/&#62;&#10;&#60;/pd&#62;</MESSAGE>
  </DATA_RECORD>
 </main>
```

When I open this file in IE9 (where test.xslt is the version of the transformation where the input is ignored and instead a literal is processed, hence the one that is OK in XML Spy), I get a processing error:

```
XML5001: Applying Integrated XSLT Handling. 
XSLT8690: XSLT processing failed.
```

Why is all this and how can I correct it?

Comment: Where are you trying to use this?  Is it in .NET code, or in IE?

Comment: It's an XML Spy transformation, to be used by manual execution or as a referred to xslt from the XML file so that the XML file can be opened in IE9. The input comes from a Toad query result save where one of the columns queried contains an XML string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the **ADDITION** above, I reached a solution by finetuning it a little.
To avoid having to do `input.text` and use plain `input` instead, the xsl has to contain a conversion of the element to a string by applying the xslt **string** function (I thought it was a string already, but apparently that is not the case). In addition, it was not necessary any more to apply the replace statements now.
Thus

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:my="http://example.com/my"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ms my">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <ms:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="my">
        <![CDATA[
        function parseToDOM (input) {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
            doc.loadXML (input);
            return doc;
        };
        ]]>
    </ms:script>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATA_RECORD">
        <xsl:variable name="msg" select="my:parseToDOM (string(MESSAGE))"/>
        <tst><xsl:value-of select="$msg/pd/cdhead/@version"/></tst>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

works: when applied on

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xslt"?>
<main>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <MESSAGE>&#60;pd&#62;&#10;    &#60;cdhead version&#61;&#34;13&#34;/&#62;&#10;&#60;/pd&#62;</MESSAGE>
  </DATA_RECORD>
 </main>
```

the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<tst>13</tst>
</root>
```

Unluckily, IE9 still fails in loading the XML with referred XSLT; and I discovered why.
I had to tick the box in Internet Options/Advanced/Security/Allow active content to run in files on My Computer - and also restart IE - this makes IE9 process the file correctly. Of course, the result not being html means that the result can only be viewed in F12/Script tab, but this was just an example and I will incorporate it in an xslt that generates proper html.